# AVD not able to create a device

Tags: android

I opened **AVD**,clicked on **create a virtual device** then I choose **nexus 5** ,clicked **next** and selected **KitKat** and pressed **next**,and then clicked **finished**. But then it just takes me to the home window of AVD which was there when I opened AVD. I cant know for sure if the device was created or not even. Can any one help me out please.If its generaring any error message where could I see it?

Comment: wait for what exactly

Answer (score 0):

avd takes lot of time to open, so you will have to wait sometime

i will suggest you to use your android mobile for running your project that way you dont have to wait.

follow this tutorial 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qb2olFyoMV4

Comment: yea but that was before, and now its way better

Answer (score 0):

What i did was opened android studio from my terminal,then did the whole process again.the error was **dumped to my terminal** and it was the problem of so many files in **my /home/kirubel/android/sdk/tools/** directory didn't have the **read-write permission**.so when i changed that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As alternative  you can use Genymotion or droi4x or Nox app player for me it's better than AVD ( you can debug your app directly to droid4x or Nox app player like you are using your android phone via usb )